# Coffeescript compiles concatentation to function application if spaces are missing?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I've found what seems to be some weird coffeescript compilation behavior, trying to determine if it's expected or not (and if so, why).

This code:

```
bob = 'test'
bobslash = bob +'/'
```

Compiles to:

```
var bob, bobslash;
bob = 'test';
bobslash = bob(+'/');
```

Rather than the expected:

```
var bob, bobslash;
bob = 'test';
bobslash = bob + '/';
```

Note the lack of space between `+` and `'\'` in the first coffeescript. Adding a space fixes the problem, and any other spacing around the `+` works. Is this expected? I didn't expect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this expected?

Well, apparently yes. It's like the second thing mentioned in the [language reference](http://coffeescript.org/#language):

> *You don't need to use parentheses to invoke a function if you're passing arguments. The implicit call wraps forward to the end of the line or block expression.*

So, with a whitespace before, but none after the plus, it is considered as the unary plus operator, applied to `'/'`, which is given as the first argument to `bob`.

> I didn't expect it.

Me neither, yet it is somehow logical. There are however 5 bug reports ([#1036](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1036), [#1395](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1395), [#2485](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2485), [#2686](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2686), [#3390](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/3390)) and an [FAQ entry](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/FAQ#grammar) about this :-)

Comment: `f +x` can have two meanings: `f(+x)` and `(f) + (x)`. Both make sense. But, `+x` and `-x` usually indicate the unary operators whereas `+ x` and `- x` (in a whitespace sensitive language) usually indicate binary operators. If `f +x` meant `f + x` then people would complain that they couldn't call `f` and cast `x` to a number at the same time and we'd have five bug reports and a FAQ entry about that :) I just throw in the function calling parentheses almost all the time so that I don't have to worry about this sort of thing.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I guess my eyes glazed over that when looking at the reference.